# Generate index.html for AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to simulate directory listing for my bucket on ASW S3. Currently I am creating "index.html" locally as follows:

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(job_dir):
    objects = []

    for obj in dirs+files:
        m_time_epoch = os.stat(os.path.join(path,obj)).st_mtime
        mtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(m_time_epoch).strftime('%c')
        size = os.stat(os.path.join(path,obj)).st_size
        type = 'dir' if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,obj)) else 'file'
        objects.append({'name': obj,
                        'mtime': mtime,
                        'size': size,
                        'type': type})

    generate_index(objects, dest_path)
```

And then passing it together with destination path (bucket URL) to a function which will create "index.html" using jinja template.

Is there better way to do it? I would like to avoid JavaScript though. I made some googling however so far did not find an elegant solution.

What would be the easiest alternative of "os.walk" using boto3 python client?

I found some snippets e.g. here:

[How do I list directory contents of an S3 bucket using Python and Boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635785/how-do-i-list-directory-contents-of-an-s3-bucket-using-python-and-boto3)

But is not there a simpler solution?

Thanks...

Comment: You could just use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). What is your _actual_ goal, beyond simply getting a directory listing?

Comment: Hi, actual goal is to put index.html into every directory (even empty). The local way with os.walk works fine (it is then synced using aws-cli) however I would like to also play with object metadata after those are uploaded. Thus I am in need of os.walk boto3 alternative. Will try what @tkwargs suggested when I am at my computer but not sure how the approach will differentiate files and directories. Played a little with "Common prefix" but so far did not come up with simple solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [`list_objects_v2`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) method in boto3.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    Bucket='MyBucket'
)

objects = []
for response in response_iterator:
    for r in response['Contents']:
        print("File is called {}".format(r['Key']))
```

While iterating through the objects in the bucket, you could build an object you could pass to a Jinja template to create the `index.html` page

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In case I need to go through every directory step-by-step like in os.walk, should I just work with the output using e.g. split() or is there better way?

Comment: S3 is key/value storage, i.e. it doesn't really have a concept of directories and sub-directories.  The AWS console provides the experience of clicking through directories and sub-directories, but under the hood it's simple key/value store. Check the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingObjects.html) for more details. If there is a lot of logic in how the keys are organized, you could use the `split()` functionality, or make multiple calls to `list_objects_v2` but add a `Prefix` to the argument

Comment: Yep, I am aware of that. I might already know what was causing my issues while using 'list_objects_v2'. It looks like the command "aws s3 sync" will put in the bucket just objects with prefixes (expected). I will try to also create a "dict object" using + "/" and will see if it helps my cause. Will update this question later. Again thanks for your time...

Comment: At the end stayed with the local way but accepting the answer as an alternative. One quick question though. If I use "resource" instead of "client" do I still need the paginator?